# How to solve the coupled first order linear differentials equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to solve the coupled first order linear differentials equations?
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \dfrac {dG}{dt} &= -k_RG-k_GG+k_FH \\
> \dfrac {dH}{dt} &= -k_HH-k_FH+k_RG\\
> \end{align}
> $$

[I will get the solution in an exponential form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkdED.png)

These two equations are for population of excited states of a molecule in chemistry.

Comment: What did you try ? Many users here are ready to **help** you but nobody will do your homework for you. So, update quickly your post.

Comment: I am new to this maths stack Exchange. So I don't know how it works. Kindly help me in solving those equations. I am a chemistry student, I tried looking in different ways of solving above equations but it doesn't lead me to the final answer.

Comment: As a welcoming gift, I posted a hint.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You face
$$\begin{align}
\dfrac {dG}{dt} &= -k_RG-k_GG+k_FH \\
\dfrac {dH}{dt} &= -k_HH-k_FH+k_RG\\
\end{align}$$
Extract $H$ from the first equation
$$H=\frac 1{k_F}\left(\dfrac {dG}{dt} +(k_R+k_G)G\right)$$ Plu this in the second equation to get
$$\frac 1{k_F}\left(\dfrac {d^2G}{dt^2} +(k_R+k_G)\dfrac {dG}{dt}\right)=-\frac{(k_H+k_F)}{k_F}\left(\dfrac {dG}{dt} +(k_R+k_G)G\right)+k_R G$$ and you face a second order equation in $G$.
$$\dfrac {d^2G}{dt^2}+a\dfrac {dG}{dt}+bG=0$$ where $$a=(k_F+k_G+k_H+k_R)\qquad \text{and} \qquad b=(k_Fk_G+k_Gk_H+k_Hk_R)$$ Now, the roots of the characteristic equation are
$$k_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{2} \left(a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4 b}\right)$$ If $a^2 >4b$ then a bi-exponential model for $G$ and $H$
$$G=c_1\,e^{-k_1t}+c_2\,e^{-k_2t}$$

Comment: @Aryadeva. Thanks for having edited the post ! Cheers :-)

Comment: You're welcome Claude.

Comment: Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Group $G,H$ in a two-components vector $v$ and the coefficients in a matrix $M$, so that you can write

$$v'=Mv.$$

Now using the Eigen decomposition of $M$ you will find a transformation that diagonalizes $M$ and

$$Tv'=\Lambda Tv$$ or, with $w=Tv$,

$$w_0'=\lambda_0 w_0,\\w_1'=\lambda_1 w_1.$$

The solutions are obviously

$$w_0=c_0e^{\lambda_0t},\\w_1=c_1e^{\lambda_1t}$$

and finally

$$v=T^{-1}w.$$